# Puppeteer: how to get httpcode in page.goto().catch?

Tags: puppeteer

I want to open a url and collect its httpcode and error, but I can't get its httpcode in goto().catch.

```
let result = {};
page.goto(url)
            .then(res => {
                result['http-code'] = res.status();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                result['http-code'] = '?'; // TODO: get http-code in goto().catch
                result['page-error'] = err + '';
            })
            .then(() => {
                res.json(result);
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible.

**TL;DR**

Because the [page.goto](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options) method will not throw an error when any valid HTTP status code is returned by the remote server, including 404 "Not Found" and 500 "Internal Server Error". The status code for such responses can be retrieved by calling `response.status()`;

[page.goto](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options) will throw an error if:

- there's an SSL error (e.g. in case of self-signed certificates).
- target URL is invalid.
- timeout is exceeded during navigation.
- the remote server does not respond or is unreachable.
  the main resource failed to load.

> **NOTE** 
>   [page.goto](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-pagegotourl-options) either throws an error or returns a main resource response. The only exceptions are navigation to about:blank or navigation to the same URL with a different hash, which would succeed and return null.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case samobody is looking for a way to navigate to a given page and get a status code (or any other information from the object [`HTTPResponse`](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.httpresponse))

```js
puppeteer.launch( puppeteerOptions ).then(async browser => {
  
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = "http://google.com";
  
  const [rsp] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.goto(url)
  ]);
  
  console.log( 200 == rsp.status() 
                  ? "Status OK"
                  : "Status NOT ok" );
  
  // ...
});
```

The first call, to `page.waitForNavigation()` returns promise which resolves after the navigation and returns the `HTTPResponse` object. The second call, `page.goto()` navigates to the given URL.
`Promise.all()` waits till both promises are resolved and returns an array with results. In this case we are interestedy only in result of the first call, which is stored in `rsp`.